# Do laser blasters shoot plasma rays like lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, blasters

I know that lightsabers consist of a plasma blade, powered by a kyber crystal, but do the Blasters in *Star Wars* work by shooting out plasma rays, too?